# why this C++ Trie implementation is showing odd behaviour?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, trie

> I implemented this class to create a trie data structure. The function

```
unsigned long Insert(string) //inserts the string in trie & return no of words in trie

void PrintAllWords(); // prints all words in trie separated by space in dictionary order
```

> implementation works correctly and prints all the words inserted from a text  file of english dictionary words when the number of words is not very large, but when supplied with a file with some 350k words it only prints out a b c d  upto z.

private variables

```
struct TrieTree
{
    std::map<char,struct TrieTree*> map_child;
    std::map<char,unsigned long> map_count; //keeps incrementing count of char in map during insertion.
    bool _isLeaf=false;  // this flag is set true at node where word ends
};

struct TrieTree* _root=NULL;
unsigned long _wordCount=0;
unsigned long _INITIALIZE=1;
```

> Below is complete implementation with driver program. The program is executable.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<fstream>
class Trie
{
private:

    struct TrieTree
    {
        std::map<char,struct TrieTree*> map_child;
        std::map<char,unsigned long> map_count;
        bool _isLeaf=false;
    };

    struct TrieTree* _root=NULL;
    unsigned long _wordCount=0;
    unsigned long _INITIALIZE=1;

    struct TrieTree* getNode()
    {
        return new TrieTree;
    };


    void printWords(struct TrieTree* Tptr,std::string pre)
    {
        if(Tptr->_isLeaf==true)
        {
            std::cout<<pre<<" ";
            return;
        }

        std::map<char,struct TrieTree*>::iterator it;
        it=Tptr->map_child.begin();
        while(it!=Tptr->map_child.end())
        {
            pre.push_back(it->first);
            printWords(it->second,pre);
            pre.erase(pre.length()-1);  //erase last prefix character
            it++;
        }

    }


public:

    Trie()
    {
        _root=getNode();
    }
    unsigned long WordCount()
    {
        return _wordCount;
    }
    unsigned long WordCount(std::string pre) //count words with prefix pre
    {
        if(WordCount()!=0)
        {
            struct TrieTree *Tptr=_root;
            std::map<char,unsigned long>::iterator it;
            char lastChar;
            for(int i=0;i<pre.length()-1;i++)
            {
                Tptr=Tptr->map_child[pre[i]];
            }
            lastChar=pre[pre.length()-1];
            it=Tptr->map_count.find(lastChar);
            if(it!=Tptr->map_count.end())
            {
                return Tptr->map_count[lastChar];
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    unsigned long Insert(std::string key)   //return word count after insertion
    {
        struct TrieTree *Tptr =_root;
        std::map<char,struct TrieTree*>::iterator it;

        if(!SearchWord(key))
        {
            for(int level=0;level<key.length();level++)
            {
                it=Tptr->map_child.find(key[level]);
                if(it==Tptr->map_child.end())
                {
                    //alphabet does not exist in map
                    Tptr->map_child[key[level]]=getNode();  // new node with value pointing to it
                    Tptr->map_count[key[level]] = _INITIALIZE;
                    Tptr=Tptr->map_child[key[level]];       //assign pointer to newly obtained node
                    if(level==key.length()-1)
                        Tptr->_isLeaf=true;
                }
                else
                {   //alphabet exists at this level
                    Tptr->map_count[key[level]]++;
                    Tptr=Tptr->map_child[key[level]];
                }
            }
            _wordCount++;
        }
        return _wordCount;
    }

    bool SearchWord(std::string key)
    {
        struct TrieTree *Tptr =_root;
        std::map<char,struct TrieTree*>::iterator it;
        for(int level=0;level<key.length();level++)
        {
            it=Tptr->map_child.find(key[level]);
         //   cout<<" "<<Tptr->map_child.size()<<endl;  //test to count entries at each map level

            if(it!=Tptr->map_child.end())
            {
                Tptr=Tptr->map_child[key[level]];
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(Tptr->_isLeaf==true)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    void PrintAllWords()
    {   //print all words in trie in dictionary order
        struct TrieTree *Tptr =_root;
        if(Tptr->map_child.empty())
            {
                std::cout<<"Trie is Empty"<<std::endl;
                return;
            }

        printWords(Tptr,"");

    }
    void PrintAllWords(std::string pre)
    {   //print all words in trie with prefix pre in Dictionary order
        struct TrieTree *Tptr =_root;
        if(Tptr->map_child.empty())
            {
                std::cout<<"Trie is Empty"<<std::endl;
                return;
            }

        for(int i=0;i<pre.length();i++)
        {
            Tptr=Tptr->map_child[pre[i]];
        }

        printWords(Tptr,pre);

    }


};

int main(){
Trie t;

std::string str;
std::fstream fs;
fs.open("words.txt",std::ios::in);

while(fs>>str){
    t.Insert(str);
}

t.PrintAllWords();

return 0;
}
```

> I don't understand the output, please take a look at the code and suggest a fix. Thanks

Comment: I suggest doing some structure validation after every insert.  Find the word that breaks your Trie and work backwards from there.  Don't just dump a program here and say "please fix".

Comment: @paddy after every insert function returns word count . Please atleast read it first before commenting. Also the map_count keeps count of words with prefix, which shows correct result.

Comment: Sorry, but please at least debug first before asking the question.  I read your question before I commented, and I saw no evidence that you had attempted to dig into this problem.  What I saw is that you wrote a whole program, and it didn't work.  You were essentially asking us to do static analysis of your code to tell you why.  Aren't you lucky that someone actually took the time to do this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the word "a", if there is no word starting with 'a' in the tree, you will add a "leaf" node with 'a' as the value. If you then add a word starting with 'a', such as "an", you will add the 'n' node as a child of the 'a' node. However, when you print all the words, you stop recursing when you hit a leaf node, meaning you ignore all the other words starting with that word.

Simple solution: remove the `return` from `printWords`.

Similarly if you already have "an" in the tree, when you add 'a', you don't mark it as a leaf, so it will never be output.

Simple solution: Set `_isLeaf` when adding a word, even if the node already exists (i.e. add `Tptr->_isLeaf=true;` to the `else` clause in `Insert`

I think you would be better off changing `_isLeaf` to something like `_isWord` as it seems odd to have leaf nodes with child items.